# Right way to use VPATH/vpath?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use my Makefile ([Make for Windows](https://chocolatey.org/packages/make)) by adding source paths to vpath/VPATH. This seems trivial but for some reason I am unable to get it to work

My directory structure is like this:

```
├── Makefile
├── out\
└── src\
    └── hello.cpp
```

My Makefile is:

```
TGT=out
OBJ=hello.o
VPATH=src
# vpath %.cpp src

all: $(TGT)\app.exe

$(TGT)\app : $(TGT)\$(OBJ)
    g++ $^ -o $@

$(TGT)\%.o : %.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c $<
```

changing to vpath didn't help me. I seem to have something fundamentally wrong here. The error I see is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `out\hello.o', needed by `out\app'.  Stop.
```

EDIT: debug output from `make -d`

```
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
 No implicit rule found for `all'.
  Considering target file `out\app'.
   File `out\app' does not exist.
    Considering target file `out\hello.o'.
     File `out\hello.o' does not exist.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `out\hello.o'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `hello'.
     Looking for a rule with intermediate file `out\hello.cpp'.
      Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
      Trying pattern rule with stem `hello.cpp'.
     No implicit rule found for `out\hello.o'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `out\hello.o'.
    Must remake target `out\hello.o'.
```

Comment: First, you should always use forward slashes in makefiles, never backslashes, even on Windows.  Second, you can use the `make -d` option to get make to tell you why it's deciding it can't match your rule.

Comment: I added the debug output. It was long, so shortened it to what seemed the important bits. So it looks like the source file is begin searched for in the out folder and VPATH isn't kicking in. I am not sure how to make it look for the source file in `src` folder. I thought VPATH would take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MadScientist points out you should avoid backslashes as they have odd results like this, had you used forward slashes throughout your Makefile you wouldn't have had this issue, that said it is possible to work around them.

There are a few things wrong here:

- You haven't posted the same Makefile you're using again, the first rule after `all` should have `$(TGT)\app.exe` as a target.
- A backslash before `%` in a pattern rule will turn it into a literal `%`, escape the backslash
- You forgot to tell gcc where to output the object file

Once you've fixed all of this you should find `vpath` works as expected, the complete fixed Makefile is

```
TGT=out
OBJ=hello.o
vpath %.cpp src

all: $(TGT)\app.exe

$(TGT)\app.exe : $(TGT)\$(OBJ)
    g++ $^ -o $@

$(TGT)\\%.o : %.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I made a new test directory structure and wrote the Makefile for it. So this Makefile is the one I was actually using. But yes your solution of escaping the backslash is indeed correct. I think its now time to replace all backslashes. Coming from unix, this slash business didn't strike me at all. Thanks!

Comment: My Makefile has a bunch of paths in it. Best practices wise, should I replace all of them with forward slashes?

Comment: @rookie I think so, if only because you no longer need to remember to escape stuff. Most windows command line actions will accept forward slashes fine anyway, the only exception I can think off the top of my head is `del`.